# Tensorflow var does not exists error and resource not found error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, carla

I am trying to run the code given by sentdex mentioned in https://pythonprogramming.net/reinforcement-learning-self-driving-autonomous-cars-carla-python/.

**Specifications:-**

Windows 10,
Carla 0.9.5,
Python 3.7.5, 
Tensorflow 1.14.0.

I am not using any GPU version of the tensorflow. I have made few changes in the imports of the code.
When I am running this code I am getting Resource not found error. Also note that an instance of carla is already running in background at port 2000 as mentioned in the code. Till now I have played with the imports by changing the locations of them along with installing different versions of tensorflow.

**Changes in import:-**

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.xception import Xception
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
```

**Error Message:-**

```
2020-02-20 01:57:14.084452: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:435: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\losses_utils.py:170: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.857485: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block5_sepconv3_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.857488: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block6_sepconv3_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.857487: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block5_sepconv3_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.858212: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block6_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.857489: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block6_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.858627: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block7_sepconv3_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.858846: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block7_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.859316: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block7_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.859587: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block7_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.859854: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block7_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.860144: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block8_sepconv3_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.857797: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block6_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.860702: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block8_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.860974: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block8_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.861245: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block8_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.861525: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block8_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.860418: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block8_sepconv3_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.862156: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block9_sepconv3_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.857490: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block6_sepconv3_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.862761: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block9_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.857727: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block13_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.861867: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block9_sepconv3_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.863594: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block9_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.863874: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block5_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.864148: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block5_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.864422: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block5_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.864696: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block5_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.863333: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block13_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.865253: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block13_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.865530: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block13_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.858415: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block7_sepconv3_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.863040: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block9_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.866358: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block4_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.866635: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block4_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.866907: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block3_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.865804: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block12_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.866094: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block4_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.867732: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block3_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.868010: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block3_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.868295: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block2_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.867185: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block3_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.867513: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block12_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.864973: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block4_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.858011: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block6_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.862487: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block9_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.870065: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block1_conv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.868855: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block2_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.869190: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block12_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.869507: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block2_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.869768: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block1_conv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.871489: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block14_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.870341: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block1_conv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.872050: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block14_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.870908: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block12_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.871215: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block14_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.872874: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block10_sepconv3_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.873155: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block10_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.873430: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block10_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.873705: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block10_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.872604: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block12_sepconv3_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.868587: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block2_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.871769: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block14_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.874838: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_v1_3/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.875136: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_v1_2/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.873983: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block10_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.874267: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block12_sepconv3_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.876008: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block11_sepconv1_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.870625: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block1_conv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.872324: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block10_sepconv3_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.875455: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_v1_2/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.875738: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_v1_1/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.874569: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_v1_3/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.876297: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block11_sepconv1_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.876570: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_v1_1/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.878266: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block11_sepconv2_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.877161: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_v1/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.877435: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block11_sepconv3_bn/beta/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.877714: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block11_sepconv3_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.877985: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/block11_sepconv2_bn/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2020-02-20 01:57:32.876877: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:260 : Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_v1/gamma/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\My_Codes\FOR_CARLA\part3.py", line 262, in train_in_loop
    self.model.fit(X,y, verbose=False, batch_size=1)
  File "C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 880, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 329, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3076, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\hrish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/dense/kernel/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[{{node dense/MatMul/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many days of research I found out that the resources were not getting initialized and hence it was saying var does not exist. So, I found few lines of codes that I pasted after graph.as_default() and before saving the model.
These are the lines of codes:-

```
session = keras.backend.get_session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)
```

I believe these lines are making things work because it was able to initialize all the  variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

1. TensorFlow version 1.14
2. numpy version 1.16.4
3. Keras version 2.2.5

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

it could be related to the GPU resources.  I did

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.5
```

and it changed to a different error. I did not have tensorflow-gpu installed before.